# Extend orthonormal system

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(e_i(x))$ be an orthonormal basis in a finite dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$ such that all maps
$$(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \ni x \mapsto e_i(x)$$
are $C^{\infty}$. I would like to know whether there does necessarily exist an extension of this map to all of $\mathbb R$ such that $x \mapsto e_i(x)$ is smooth and $(e_i(x))$ for an orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=2$ and $e_1(x)=\frac 1 {f(x)} (\frac 1 {x-\epsilon},log |x-\epsilon|)$, $e_2(x)=\frac 1 {f(x)} (-log |x-\epsilon|, \frac 1 {x-\epsilon})$ where 
 $f(x)=\sqrt {(log |x-\epsilon|)^{2}+\frac 1 {(x-\epsilon)^{2}}}$ 
 then no extension is possible.

Comment: You can factor out $(x-\epsilon)^2$ to get $$e_1(x)=\frac{(x-\epsilon,1)}{\sqrt{(x-\epsilon)^2+1}}$$ which can certainly be smoothly extended. But here's a different counterexample: $$e_1(x)=(\cos\frac1{x-\epsilon},\sin\frac1{x-\epsilon})$$

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you for pointing out the error. I have modified the definition in a different way. I think my functions can be extended continuously but they cannot be extended to $C^{\infty}$ functions.