# Smooth Orthonormal system

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(e_i(x))$ be an orthonormal basis in a finite dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$ such that all maps
$$(-2\varepsilon,2\varepsilon) \ni x \mapsto e_i(x)$$
are $C^{\infty}$. I would like to know whether there does necessarily exist an extension of the map 
$$(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \ni x \mapsto e_i(x)$$ to all of $\mathbb R$ such that $x \mapsto e_i(x)$ is smooth and $(e_i(x))$ for an orthonormal basis?

See for a previous question of mine that is related to this one:
[Extend orthonormal system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470234/extend-orthonormal-system)

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: An upvote for the modification you made to your previous question!

Comment: @KaboMurphy thank you, also thanks for pointing out the issue in the previous post.

Comment: I think you should be able to use [smooth step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) in the interval $(\varepsilon,\tfrac32\varepsilon)$ to make the $e_i$ decay until they're constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the [smooth step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function)

$$g(x)=0,\quad x\leq0$$

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac1x-\frac1{1-x}\right)},\quad0<x<1$$

$$g(x)=1,\quad1\leq x$$

and some $\kappa>\varepsilon$ to construct a set of vector functions (not necessarily independent)

$$f_i(x)=e_i(x),\quad0\leq x\leq\varepsilon$$

$$f_i(x)=g(\tfrac{\kappa-x}{\kappa-\varepsilon})e_i(x)+g(\tfrac{x-\varepsilon}{\kappa-\varepsilon})e_i(\kappa),\quad\varepsilon<x<\kappa$$

$$f_i(x)=e_i(\kappa),\quad\kappa\leq x.$$

The step function has all derivatives $g^{(n)}(0)=g^{(n)}(1)=0$ at the endpoints, so the $f_i$ are smooth.

Since $f_i(\varepsilon)=e_i(\varepsilon)$ are independent (which can be rephrased as $\det[f_i(\varepsilon)]\neq0$, or as $f_1(\varepsilon)\wedge f_2(\varepsilon)\wedge\cdots\wedge f_n(\varepsilon)\neq0$), and the $f_i$ are also continuous functions of $\kappa$, there must exist some $\kappa$ such that $f_i(x)$ are independent on the interval $\varepsilon<x<\kappa$. (I'm not quite sure about this part.)

Now we can apply the Gram-Schmidt process:

$$\overline f_1(x)=f_1(x)$$

$$\overline f_2(x)=f_2(x)-\frac{f_2(x)\cdot f_1(x)}{f_1(x)\cdot f_1(x)}f_1(x)$$

$$\overline f_3(x)=f_3(x)-\frac{f_3(x)\cdot f_1(x)}{f_1(x)\cdot f_1(x)}f_1(x)-\frac{f_3(x)\cdot f_2(x)}{f_2(x)\cdot f_2(x)}f_2(x)$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\hat f_i(x)=\frac{\overline f_i(x)}{\sqrt{\overline f_i(x)\cdot\overline f_i(x)}}$$

The dot product is a smooth function, and division and square roots are smooth at non-zero inputs, so $\hat f_i$ are smooth and orthonormal.

Apply a similar construction for negative $x$.